# binary value not getting updated in database through php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update status onclick. In display function i have given like this

```
if($row['IsActive']=="1")
{
    echo "<td> <a href='managecategories.php?IsActive=0&CategoryID=" .$row['CategoryID']. "'>Active</a></td>";
}
else
{
    echo "<td> <a href='managecategories.php?IsActive=1&CategoryID=" .$row['CategoryID']. "'>Deactive</a></td>";
}
```

and on loading the page it should get the database status, for that i have written code like this

```
      if (isset($_GET['IsActive']))
{
$status = $_GET['IsActive'];
$id = $_GET['CategoryID'];
 if($status =="0")

{

$sql = "update Categories set IsActive= 0 where CategoryID='$id'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Could not insert data into DB: " . mysql_error());
}        
else 
 if($status =="1")
{
$sql = "update Categories set IsActive= 1 where CategoryID='$id'";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Could not insert data into DB: " . mysql_error());
}        
}
```

But i am not getting any result not errors... please hel me where i am wrong

Comment: yup. 1st time it will be array(0){} but after clicking the 1st link i got the result something like this array(2) { ["IsActive"]=> string(1) "1" ["CategoryID"]=> string(2) "14" }, but am not getting what is this.

Comment: `echo` your `$sql` queries and see what they're outputting, you could also add an `else` after your `else if($status)`, and an `else` after checking `if(isset($_GET['isActive']))` - (put some debug messages in there or something), that way all eventualities are covered and you can see what's going on.

Comment: On a side note, you have an SQL injection vulnerability there `CategoryID='$id'` - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would assume that you are using an integer type in the database. I know I would use `TINYINT` for any boolean, because MySQL does not have a type boolean.
Your display function `if($row['IsActive']=="1")` supports that. However, your update query `$sql = "update Categories set IsActive= 'false' where CategoryID='$id'";` does not. Here you try to save a string value.

So you should first make sure that the boolean value is stored as a `TINYINT` in the database. (Strings are harder to work with on the PHP side.) Then you need to make sure that the values you insert into the database are actually of the correct type. You should use 0 for `false` and 1 for `true`. That will also work in PHP:

```
$isActive = 1;
$if($isActive) {
   // This code is run
}
```

Also note that you should validate the category id. You're now inserting user input without prior validation, which is dangerous. It is quite easy for a user to activate or deactive all categories in a single command.

Comment: i have changed datatype as TYNYINT in my database, it was bit earlier. and changed value to 0 from false. still it is not working :(

Comment: Did you also change `true` to `1`?

Comment: Yup. I have changed it. and i tried changing the datatype as integer in database. It was tynyint earlier. but still its the same

Comment: I don't see anything strange in your code now. If things don't work, you need to find out exactly what your input values are. In PHP, that is. Then determine which path your code should take, and verify that it does take that option. Don't assume but validate and verify.

Comment: Yup. Sorry. I validtaed the . Getting the data from the database had some error. Corrected it. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you don't have `true` and `false`, but only `0` and `1` (`INT`). So change your queries to something like this:

```
$sql = "update Categories set IsActive= 0 where CategoryID='$id'"; // FALSE
$sql = "update Categories set IsActive= 1 where CategoryID='$id'"; // TRUE
```

Additionally I see that in the first piece of code you ***correctly*** do this: if row *is active* print a link to deactivate (`if 1 then print 0`), and viceversa.

But in the second piece of code you get the value you have to set in the `$status` variable, and then you say again `if 1 then store 0`. This is a mistake. In fact, this way you always run an UPDATE query that set the *active* status to its current value, because of the *double swap*.

That is, try to swap the queries in the second piece of code, like this:

```
if ($status == "0") 
{
    $sql = "update Categories set IsActive=0 where CategoryID='$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Could not insert data into DB: " . mysql_error());
}        
else if($status == "1")
{
    $sql = "update Categories set IsActive=1 where CategoryID='$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die("Could not insert data into DB: " . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Yes i have changed this to 0 still its not taking. Nothing is updating to database. I don't know where i am wrong

Comment: @user1321271 No, you changed nothing. See my answer, my code. When `status` is `"1"` it means you asked for *activate* the row. So the corresponding query must be `IsActive=1`, not `0`. And viceversa.

Comment: Sorry. I have changed it and Ran. But all the rows links are showing only deactivate. After clicking also the same it doesn't changes.

Comment: I cannot help you more than this. Review all your code and try to emulate in your mind with PHP and MySQL do.